# How to expose static files from django container to nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm trying to expose static files from inside a django docker container so the globally (not in a container) installed nginx can serve static files. What is important i want to do it using ansible.

I tried to use volume pointing to public folder inside container, but docker clears this folder when running container.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN python manage.py migrate
CMD gunicorn testdocker.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Static root directory is in /usr/src/app/public

Finally, nginx should server static files which are inside docker container.

Comment: If you already have something in `/usr/src/app/public` directory and don't want it t be cleared, then you can mount your container static files to some child directory like `/usr/src/app/public/static` and configure nginx to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is an isolation mechanism, and one of the things this means is that processes on the host can't see files inside a Docker container.  The various mechanisms to share files between the host and containers generally support use cases of either providing an empty directory to share content, or pushing content from the host into the container, but not getting container files out.

The best way to approach this is to set up your CI system to produce two sets of artifacts.  One is the Docker image you show above.  Separately, *starting from the original source tree*, produce a bundle of static artifacts.  Once you have this bundle of artifacts, deploy it to nginx.

(In other words, figure out how you'd solve this problem without Docker involved, and just do that.)

(There are two other ways I can think of to do this: use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy content out of the container once it's started, or set up a pre-launch script inside the container to copy static assets into some bind-mounted directory.  Both of these feel more complicated and more tied to this very specific deployment path.)

Comment: The problem is that static files produced strongly depend on built docker image.  And this is why I use docker but on same server will be more dockerized python apps so I want to use one globally operated nginx as reversed proxy + serving static files and I don't see easy solution.